# URL expands when processed by jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, laravel, laravel-4

I have a button to load some content into a DIV:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_toolbox" get-what="partial/answer_question/{{ $ae->item_id }}">get the answer</button>
```

the jquery code which processes the request is

```
$('button').click(function() {
var questionid = $(this).attr("get-what"); 
$('#mt-placeholder').load(questionid);
```

Problem: 
the url of the page where the button is located is 
myapp.com/exemplars/4

and the URL i call by jquery gives this:

```
local.ERROR: 404 - Exception @ /exemplars/partial/answer_question/91
```

My usual solution in such cases: 
in the L-4 application I just put 
    {{URL::to('')}}
but it cannot be applied here.

My working solution: 
I just add ../ to the

```
get-what="../partial/answer_question/{{ $ae->item_id }}"
```

**My question:**
I don't think that my workaround is a good practice.
How to get the proper URL in the above solution? Or how I can get the desired result using in a better/proper way?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

As the current page is in the `/exemplars` folder, that's what any relative address will use as origin. If you want to use the web root as origin, you can use a virtual address instead, i.e. start it with a slash to specify the root:

```
get-what="/partial/answer_question/{{ $ae->item_id }}"
```